# Speed ​up Roslyn solution analyser

Tags: reflection, msbuild, static-analysis, class-diagram, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm developing a tool to visualize programs written in C#, including .sln, .csproj, and .cs files. It has functionality for displaying project references, class diagrams, and method diagrams. However, I've encountered a problem: it takes much more time than I expected to load a .sln file. Is there any way to speed up the process of loading .sln files, considering my specific needs?
I believe it performs more actions than necessary.

I tried examining the MSBuildWorkspace class to find any properties that could make it perform fewer actions, but it didn't help.